# Is this part of my bougainvillea or a weed?

Tags: identification, shrubs, weeds

This plant has started growing in my bougainvillea and there's some debate going on in the house whether it is a weed, or part of the bougainvillea, perhaps the male part. I'm unable to find any pictures of bougainvillea's that have this in them.

Plant in question:

[image: Questionable plant]

Bougainvillea:

[image: Bougainvillea]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some further research, and with the help of @Escoce's and @Bamboo's answers, I believe this is a [Sweet Almond Bush](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/59091/).

- Family: Verbenaceae
- Genus: Aloysia
- Species: Virgata

[image: Sweet Almond Bush]

<sup>©Dave's Garden / http://pics.davesgarden.com/pics/2006/05/07/aprilwillis/bfe970.jpg</sup>

Answer (score 10):

It looks like a mint or a very closely related labitae. Even the flower spike looks like mint. Is the stem squarish?

In any case it is certainly not part of your bougainvillea.

Answer (score 5):

Agree with @Escoce's answer, point given, but note also there is no separate 'male part' in Bougainvillea, the flowers contain both male and female components, although they are not self fertile. This is definitely a separate plant growing behind and through your Bougainvillea.